# Forcing to download files on all <a> tags using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm implementing a checkout process on digital content. When the user places the order, then I show him all the products that he has purchased along with the download link of each next to the product. My client wants that when success page is loaded then all the products should download automatically.

Here are the code snippets:

HTML code snippet of the page where there is download link of the product

```
<p>Some digital product name</p>
<a class='digital-download' href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->getBaseUrl('true'); ?>/site/downloadfile/filename/<?php echo $digital_download['filename']; ?>">Click here download</a>
```

My PHP code for the action that initiates the download of file(downloadfile action):

```
public function actionDownloadFile($filename) {
    $file = Yii::app()->request->getBaseUrl(true) . '/upload/digitaluploads/' . $filename; //file location
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
    readfile($file);
}
```

Now since my client wants that all the files should download automatically when the page is loaded, I tried following using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('.digital-download').each(function() {
        var download_link = $(this).attr("href");
        window.location = download_link;
    });
});
```

The problem:

It only initiates the download of first file and download of other files is not initiated. Moreover following jQuery event does not work at all:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.digital-download').each(function() {
        $(this).click();
    });
});
```

Any solutions?

Comment: It would probably be a better solution to create a zip file on the server containing all the files in the bundle which would then be downloaded as a single file.

Comment: Not what I want. Client wants that each product purchased download separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this using single window (`window.location`) - because the browsers limit one page load per window. Download is initiated at page load - when content type is not acceptable or is meant to be downloaded.

In my opinion best workaround is using `iframes`

```
$('a.digital-download').each(function(){
    $('<iframe></iframe>', {src: $(this).attr('href')})
        .css({
            width:0,
            height:0,
            border:'none'
        })
        .appendTo('body');
});
```

Download links are collected from anchor elements and added to newly created `iframe` elements. `Iframes` are essentially embedded windows. Later when `iframes` are appended to page - multiple page loads are initiated and multiple downloads are started.

**EDIT**: Recently had to make this solution work with pure JavaScript

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body'),
    elements = document.getElementsByClassName('digital-download'),
    element, src;
for(var I in elements)
{
    if(elements.hasOwnProperty(I) && elements[I].attributes.length > 0)
    {
        src = null;
        for(var O in elements[I].attributes)
        {
            if(elements[I].attributes.hasOwnProperty(O) && elements[I].attributes[O].name == 'href')
            {
                src = elements[I].attributes[O].value;
            }
        }
        if(typeof src != 'undefined' && null !== src)
        {
            element = document.createElement('iframe');
            element.style.width = 0;
            element.style.height = 0;
            element.style.borderWidth = 0;
            body[0].appendChild(element);
            element.src = src;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great...that worked for me. But could you explain the logic behind that how it initiates the download? and how appendTo is relevant to this?

Comment: Iframes work like embedded windows, they request page you give in `src` attribute and as response headers contain `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` browser starts to download given content like they do in normal windows.
As you see I used styling to make it 0x0px and without border, so it wouldn't be hidden but invisible anyway because some browsers ignore iframes if they are hidden by `display` or `visibility` properties.
By using jQuery constructor with full tags in it `$('<iframe></iframe')` you create new DOM object and then using `.appendTo()` method inject it into HTML document.

Comment: Upon injection your new DOM object is being rendered by browser, sends request to url given in `src` attribute and waits for response.

Comment: That's nice. Thank you for explaining that.